# How to configure TinyMCE editor event to be fired only once?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a requirement to fire the '**SetContent**' event only once. I've tried

```
var ed = tinymce.get("editor");
ed.on('SetContent', function(e) {
    // Turns off event so that it doesn't fire again
    ed.off('SetContent');
    //  Performs the task that need to be performed once
});
ed.setContent('some content');
```

I'm using TinyMCE Version: 4.9.2-120

The above code raises a JavaScript error and doesn't work.

There's a link on TinyMCE website that says it is feasible
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.off.static

Can someone guide me through?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've solved the issue.

Basically, there's a function that allows you to run an event only once. Use that like this:

```
var ed = tinymce.get("editor");
ed.once('SetContent', function(e) {
    //  Performs the task that need to be performed once
});
ed.setContent('some content');
```

I hope this will be of some help to someone.